# Getting list of regions that lines intersect with using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, table

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a bunch of line features with unique ids and a bunch of polygons with unique ids. I want to know how many and which polygons each line interacts with. The only way I know how to do this is to Spatial Join and get the join count. But this wouldnt give me the unique ids of all the polygons the lines intersect with.

I am not a GIS expert, this is something I learned for my job and to me it feels like I want to flip the way database table's x and y axis. I often encounter this problem where I want to have a series of information in a cell. I feel like there must be a way to do this that I have not learned yet.
[image]

Comment: @BERA I can only get a list of join count. THe option in Spatial join only lets me sum, range, median, etc. There is no option to make a list of the of the Region ID's.

Comment: @BERA when I do it with Intersect it creates makes the lines have the region information, I want to make the regions have the information that all the lines going through it have. Does that make any sense? Thank s for your help?

Comment: @BERA the table shown is of the lines. 
https://i.imgur.com/hrDK51x.png 
It has all the Topo_ID's (Regions) that i intersects with. I want to get that information into the Regions (Topois) and consolidate the information so that if Region A can get to Region by two different lines it only counts it as getting to Region B once.